# Select multiple options in a single attribute in catalog

Tags: attributes, filter, custom-attributes, multiselect-attribute, magento2.4.4

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's by design, or if it's a theme. I've added a custom option (size) and enabled it for catalog pages, it does display as a filter on the left. However I cannot select multiple choices, for example choose to filter both "XL" and "S" sizes at once. When I click on the option, it immediately transfers me to that single size filter. Plus the picker looks weird: it displays both the radio button and the checkbox. What to do? Where to look?
Magento version 2.4.4
[image]

Comment: Post the code and Magento version, please.

Comment: Hi , my solution for your query is that - No it is not possible to do with the default magento configurations , you can achieve it by customisation in code level , or you can look for 3rd party extensions which have achieved this customisation.Thanks

Comment: I don't have a custom code there, magento version added.

Comment: So perhaps the answer is that this functionality isn't built in Magento and I really need to use an extension (or code one myself), like this one - https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-layered-navigation-extension.html ?

Comment: And this one is even free... https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite